# How to convert elements of a column to a list in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df like

```
A B     C
1 2 {'id':1}
3 3 {'id':2}
5 4 {'id':3}
```

I want an output like this.

```
A B     C
1 2  [{'id':1}]
3 3  [{'id':2}]
5 4  [{'id':3}]
```

Any  help please. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
df['C'] = df['C'].apply(lambda x : [x])
```